# In Java, classes with a run() method are not allowed as argument to new Thread()

Tags: java, multithreading

If I make a new Java class as follows:

```
class A 
{
   public void run() {
       // do something
   }
}
```

And then I do this:

```
new Thread(new A()).start()
```

Then I expect it to run the run() method.  But it does not.

Why can't we pass any object having the run method as an argument to new Thread()?

Why can't java just allow any class with a run() method to run?  Would there be a problem to have java implement threads in this way?

Comment: That's how Java works, it's strong typed - have a look at the Java tutorial to get the basics right: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: The Thread constructor takes a Runnable object as a parameter.  Without implementing the interface, the compiler can't know that your class is a subtype of Runnable, even if it conforms to the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what a language with [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (like JavaScript for example) would do. Java is not such a language. Two classes having the same methods are unrelated. What is important is the inhertiance relationship between their classes.

Since the `Thread` constructor accepts a `Runnable` as argument, only instances of classes which implements the `Runnable` interface can be passed as argument.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't use [structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

Answer (score 1):

Make class `A` implement the Runnable interface.  Then it will work.

The compiler needs to assure type safety, and by providing the Runnable interface you guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

A `Thread` wants to invoke a routine, and in java it's defined as `run()`. The *only* way to do that is if it **knows** the passed object has a `run()` method. The object oriented approach to this problem is defining an interface which **forces** the presence of a `run()` method.

Comment: The compiler or runtime could (in theory) check for the presence of a `run()` method.

Comment: @Steve, yes, and Reflection *could* be used. But as java is strongly type that behaviour is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Because Java doesn't work that way.

Long answer: Thread has several constructors, one of which takes an instance of a class implementing the Runnable interface as a parameter.  If a class doesn't implement this interface, it cannot be used.

An interface is a guarantee of structure.  A class implementing Runnable is guaranteed to implement a method with the signature `public void run()` which raises no checked Exceptions and returns nothing.  Without the interface, this becomes more difficult to a) check and b) enforce

Answer (score 0):

Because `Thread` requires `Runnable` instance (object implementing `Runnable`), not *something that has a `run()` method*.

This feature is called *duck typing* and is implemented e.g. in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like the same interface, of course, because you have "run()" in it.  But that's not how Java works.  Thread needs an object that implements the Runnable interface.  That means the Java compiler can piece together the code ahead of time because it knows where it will find the run() method.  The interface points to it, in a matter of speaking.  When you implement that interface, you're "filling the slot" that the thread constructor has already been set to point at.  The interface knits things together, lining things up so that everything matches up.  A computer language *could* be defined that allows what you are asking for, but then there would have to be all sorts of analysis to find things, and then further checks to detect when the contract was broken -- it would be highly inefficient and error prone.  Interfaces make it easier for *both* the Java compiler *and* the Java programmer.